# Android studio cannot run on your computer

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

I'm trying to install Android studio on my new computer but every time I click on .exe file I get this error:

> This app cannot run on your computer , to find your computer version check the software publisher

I go through the guide exactly.

I'm using Windows 10, 64 bit but the installation file is support both
32/64 bit

Comment: Can you provide more information? Where did you download it from? Can you post a screenshot of the error?